# Minimum Jump Array Recursive Time Complexity should be O(n^n) or O(n!)

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, time-complexity

I was checking "minimum number of jumps to reach the end" problem in GeekforGeeks https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimum-number-of-jumps-to-reach-end-of-a-given-array/ .
I got confused about the time complexity mentioned there which is O(n^n).

```
// Returns minimum number of
// jumps to reach arr[h] from arr[l]
static int minJumps(int arr[], int l, int h)
{
    // Base case: when source
    // and destination are same
    if (h == l)
        return 0;
 
    // When nothing is reachable
    // from the given source
    if (arr[l] == 0)
        return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
 
    // Traverse through all the points
    // reachable from arr[l]. Recursively
    // get the minimum number of jumps
    // needed to reach arr[h] from these
    // reachable points.
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (int i = l + 1; i <= h
                        && i <= l + arr[l];
         i++) {
        int jumps = minJumps(arr, i, h);
        if (jumps != Integer.MAX_VALUE && jumps + 1 < min)
            min = jumps + 1;
    }
    return min;
}
```

If I see the above code block, minJumps(arr, i, h) recursive call is getting called from i=l+1. So in every recursive step, l(start position) is getting incremented by 1. Time complexity should be calculated as below.

```
T(N) = (n-1)*(n-2)*(n-3)...*1
     = (n-1)!
```

I am not getting why time complexity is O(n^n). In few other places also, I saw time complexity for this recursive solution is mentioned as O(n^n) without a proper explanation. Please help me out with a simple explanation & point out what I am missing here.

Comment: How are you factoring out the 2 when its out of the equation?

Comment: I think it's O((n-1)! ) but you're right. That website is just being a bit sloppy with their complexities -- it's not wrong that it's O(n^n) since big O is an upper bound, but that's not a tight bound.

Comment: I didn't understand why you multiplied every value.

Comment: Seems like `O(2^n)` to me. Not sure though.

Comment: @Shantanu I made a correction to the equation now.

Comment: @PaulHankin you are right. I understood why time complexity can be O(n-1)! now & updated my calculation accordingly.

Comment: Actually, I think I'm not right, and @potter1024 has it right in their answer.

Comment: @PaulHankin I think O((n-1)!) is not a wrong answer as you rightly mentioned that big O just defines the upper bound. But potter1024's answer improves the upper bound as O(2^n).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see the recurse relation as `T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) + T(n-3) + T(n-4) + ... + T(0)`, since the loop is from l to h (ignore the `if` condition for now). So for an interval `[l,h]` every value in that interval will be called in the worst case that is `minJumps(l+1, h), minJumps(l+2, h) ... minJumps(h, h)` and it can be noticed that the above recurse relation holds here.

Now, solving the relation, we can write it as `T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-1)` as `T(n-1) = T(n-2) + T(n-3) + T(n-4) + ... + T(0)`. Hence `T(n) = 2 * T(n-1)` which boils down to `O(2^n)`.

The time complexity of the mentioned algorithm should be `O(2^n)`.

Comment: You're right! The easiest way to see that it's 2^n is that there's one path per subset of indices of A. (ie: subsets of {1, 2, 3, ..., n}).